# Remove padding when number of zeros can change

Tags: c#, regex

I have an string which is always 12 digits long

Its starts with 'PSS1'

'PSS100000300'

So I need to extract '300'

I can't just grab the last 3 digits as the number can increase to say

'PSS100010300'

And would need the value extracted to be '10300'

Comment: You didn't ask a question; this is a question-and-answer site. You just told a story about what you want.  Ask a question!

Comment: Hows it not a question?

Comment: get a substring removing the `PSS1` and convert to an integer.

Comment: Which sentence asks a question?

Comment: This is going to be very tough. What if the number doesn't have zeros... like PSS123456789? Or what if the first digit increments like PSS200010300?

Comment: @Jeff: The statement of the problem is that it always starts with `PSS1`.

Comment: Because there is no questionmark???? :)

Comment: The lack of any question marks would be a clue. Questions are things like "Here's what I expect, but the code (included) I've tried gives... What am I doing wrong?"

Comment: I didn't create the formatting which start with PSS1...

Comment: @EricLippert I saw that but I think I was bringing additional assumptions to the table. Thanks for bringing me back. It's still going to be tough. What if the number is PSS111100123? Is the right output 11100123 or 123? The 'question' isn't defined well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
s = Convert.ToInt32(s.Replace("PSS1", string.Empty)).ToString()
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understood correctly, you want to skip first 4 characters and then zeross till the first non-zero characters. Try this one:

```
s = new string(s.Substring(4).SkipWhile(x => x == '0').ToArray());
```

Or, as @Blorgbeard suggested,

```
s = int.Parse(s.Substring(4)).ToString();
```

---

There is a slight difference between the methods. If you pass `"PSS100000000"`, the first one returns an empty string, the second one returns `"0"`. Not sure which result is expected.

Comment: I'd prefer `int.Parse(s.Substring(4)).ToString()`

Comment: Yeah thats what I'm after, thanks Alex and BlorgBeard

Comment: @Blorgbeard Thanks! Do you mind that I copied it to the answer?

Comment: Not at all, I'd have posted it as an answer myself if I cared enough :)

Comment: @Stan I updated the answer to mention behavior for `0..0`-string.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with using `int.Parse` is that if you happen to ever come across this situation and the value you are after is not a number - let's say it might have a character in it...the `int.Parse` will throw an `Exception`.

That is why I would do it like this:

```
string fullPSS1String = "PSS10000#001";
string afterPSS1 = fullPSS1String.Substring(4).TrimStart('0');
```

I am not being picky, just trying to think of all situations.  I know that the first option would not throw an `Exception`...but I feel that doing it this way is more direct.